# API AND ABI in a nutshell

Tags: c++, api, abi

please can't figure out what is an API and an ABI in simple words (no wikipedia definitions please) ,  are they a part of the kernel ?  are they functions ?  what do they do ?

Comment: Did you hover your mouse pointer over the tags. The tag info appearing gives the explanation in a nutshell pretty well IMHO.

Comment: I've already done it , it's a Wikimedia definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API is an *application programming interface*. It provides a way for different source-level software components to communicate with each other.

An example of an API would be a header file for a library, which specifies a set of functions provided by the library and how to call them. For example, in C++:

```
//external_library.h
//Processes your data and writes the results to outputlog.txt
void ProcessMyData (std::string data);
```

This tells a programmer using `external_library` that they can call a function called `ProcessMyData`. This function takes in a `std::string`, returns nothing, and (if the documentation is up-to-date) writes the results to `outputlog.txt`.

---

An ABI is an *application binary interface*. It provides a standard way for binary components to communicate with both the platform and each other.

An example of an ABI would be the System V ABI. This specifies various details such as function calling conventions, binary data representations, object file formats, loading, linking, etc. You can read a draft of the SysV ABI for AMD64 processors [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) to get an idea of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

**API** Application Programming Interface

That means the functions and classes a programmer uses to write a program. The functions and classes provided by a library are its **API**.

**ABI** Application Binary Interface.

This is the low-level way that functions and classes are laid out in memory after a program has been compiled. Linking part of a compiled program to a compiled library or another part of a compiled program requires the pieces to be laid out in the same way so everything fits together properly.

Comment: what do u mean with low level ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis I mean the way they are laid out in memory. *C++ source code* is written in words (high level). When the *C++ source code* is compiled (converted into a program) it is converted into binary numbers (low level).

Comment: and how do they get laid in memory ? are they processessed with functions ?

Comment: How they are laid out in memory is platform dependent. For example when you call a function, the parameters need to be put somewhere so the called function can find them. Where they are put is part of the ABI.

Comment: thank's , with that out PhD the way I can continue learning